# In a bipartite graph $\alpha \beta \geq m$

Tags: graph-theory

That's basically it. $\alpha$ is the cardinality of the biggest independent set (no pair of vertices is connected) and $\beta$ is the cardinality of the smallest covering by vertices.

I know this (let's say that $|Y|\leq|X|$, where $X,Y$ are the partitions of our graph and $m$ and $n$ are the number of edges and vertices):

- $\beta\leq|Y|\leq|X|\leq\alpha$ by the maximality/minimality of $\alpha$ and $\beta$
- $\alpha+\beta=n$
- $m\leq|Y||X|$
- $|Y|+|X|=n$

I've manipulated this inequalities in so many ways (AM-GM, squaring, replacing from $|Y|+|X|=\alpha+\beta$) but I always reach a dead point, with the inequalities reversed (like $m\leq \text{something}\geq \alpha\beta$) which is really frustrating.

Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: what are m and n?

Comment: $m$ is the number of edges and $n$ the number of vertices.

Answer (score 1):

Let $G$ be a bipartite graph. Let us consider the partite sets $X$ and $Y$($|X|\geq |Y|$) chosen such that for all other partite sets $A$ and $B$($|A|\geq |B|$) of $G$, $|X|-|Y|\geq |A|-|B|$. I claim that $Y$ is a minimum vertex covering.

To see this, assume there exists a vertex covering $Z$ with $|Z|<|Y|$. Then $Z$ and $V(G)-Z$ are partite sets since every edge of $G$ is incident with a vertex in $Z$. Observe that $|V(G)-Z|-|Z|>|X|-|Y|$ giving us a contradiction. Thus $Y$ is a minimum vertex covering.

Then $|Y|=\beta$ and so $|X|=\alpha$. Then $\alpha *\beta\geq m$.

Comment: $\alpha = |X|$ and $\beta=|Y|$ only if the graph is complete, consider for example a graph with an isolalted vertex.

Comment: @Hermine that is why you choose X and Y to maximize $|X|-|Y|$. That way all the isolated vertices are in X. This forces X to be a maximum independent set(or you could make X bigger) and Y to be a minimum covering(or you could make Y smaller)

Comment: Is that clear, or should I go into detail how we know that choosing X and Y correctly forces this?

Comment: It's not clear, but I found another way using the fact that $m=\sum d(v)$. I'll post it as answer later.

Comment: @Hermine I added a little bit explaining how to easily see how this is forced.

Comment: I don't see how you guarantee $V(G)\setminus Z$ and $Z$ to be partite sets. Just because $Z$ is a covering doesn't mean it has no internal edge connections.